# Erroneous foreign key having many values per primary key value?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, key, primary-key, cascade

I'm re-learning primary and foreign keys from an example at [Source Daddy](http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/primary-key-constraint.html) about various manufacturers of various toys:

```
CREATE TABLE Manufacturers
(
    ManufacturerID INTEGER CONSTRAINT ManfID PRIMARY KEY,
    ToyID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CompanyName CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Address CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    City CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    State CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    PostalCode CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    AreaCode CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber CHAR(8) NOT NULL UNIQUE,

    CONSTRAINT ToyFk 
        FOREIGN KEY (ToyID) REFERENCES Toys (ToyID)
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

While I don't use keys a lot, I think I understand them. I'm puzzled by the example above. This is a manufacturer table and there is another table of toys.  We can expect a mapping of many toys to any one manufacturer. So it doesn't seem to make sense to have a Toy ID field in a table of manufacturers, unless, for any given manufacturer record, that field is meant to contain a collection of Toy IDs.

Sure, you can use a string to do this [1], but the purpose of this example doesn't seem to be to confusing things with weird exotic examples.

Have I stunningly misunderstood keys all these years? If so, can anyone explain away the above problem?

Thanks.

P.S. If I am right, then the error totally confuses the [next page](http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/foreign-key-constraint.html), which tries to describe the direction of updates arising from `CASCADE`.

[1] Or do it in Matlab, which allows complex cells.

Comment: Presumably in this database each manufacturer only provides one toy.

Comment: That is so counterintuitive, but possible.  It would defeat the purpose of illustrating a typical use of primary & foreign keys.  And there are no hints about it in the code that creates the [toy table](http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/constraints.html).  Does the toy table actually get updated in response to changes to the manufacturer table, vice-versa, or both?  (Feel like posting your comment as the answer?  I somehow don't expect a better explanation to be forthcoming).

Comment: Either Access is *really* weird or this is a bad tutorial that you shouldn't be trying to learn from. Or both. A normal design would have the Toys table include a foreign key referencing Manufacturers.ManufacturerID.

Comment: No, I pushed Access SQL to its limits for analysis (not production), so this is unorthodox even for Access.  But it did make me wonder whether I was misconceived about foreign & primary keys, not having used them much.  I'm getting the sense that my understanding is OK, and the example is simply...not ideal.  Thanks for the sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

The point of a (pardon the pun) toy problem is to have intuitive & simple semantics, but this design doesn't, so it is a poor & confusing example.

An SQL PK (primary key) is some UNIQUE set of NOT NULL columns that you chose to call PK. An SQL FK (foreign key) is a column list whose subrows appear elsewhere as a declared UNIQUE (possibly a PK). Declare PKs, UNIQUE NOT NULLs, UNIQUEs & FKs as they arise when not implied by other declarations. Also a declared FK must be to a declared UNIQUE/PK, so you have to have to declare such a UNIQUE/PK even if it is implied by other declarations. A DMBS might use PKs for further purposes.

Comment: Thanks, philipxy.  Can you clarify what you mean by a column list and subrows?  I've not come across them as formal terms before in my SQLing.  Also, how are PKs, UNIQUE [NOT NULLs], and FKs "implied" by other declarations?  Thanks!

Comment: By set, list, row & subrow I just mean the CS notions. Unfortunately SQL culture does not have adequate common terminology for talking clearly re SQL. In the RM (relational model) PK, AK, FK, constraint, relation/table, tuple/row, etc mean certain things different from SQL--partly "because" SQL table values are bags & have nulls & SQL is just different & SQL culture is sloppy & ill-informed. A RM FK is a column set. But this is the sort of thing that simply has no common SQL terminology--there is just a "[declared] FK constraint" expression giving name+table+list+table+list & a restriction.

Comment: A SQL FK constraint says that certain subrows of values that appear in the rows of a base table have to appear elsewhere as certain subrows of values in the rows of a base table as UNIQUE values. PS Surely after "all these years" you know that a PK/UNIQUE/FK can be composite/compound? (You can't declare it but they can also be empty.)

Comment: In the RM a constraint is a restriction on what the DB can be. In SQL we also use the term to mean a thing that we declared that has associated name & restriction & base table names & column lists. When one or more constraint-as-restrictions hold, others do. So when you declare one or more for enforcement, others that you could have declared are enforced even though you didn't. Eg: T (C,D) references U (C,D) implies that T(C) references U (C). If also U (C,D) references V (D,C) [sic] then T(C,D) references V (D,C) [sic] but these restrictions are enforced without needing declaration.

Comment: I too prefer UNIQUE set of NOT NULL columns. But I rolled back your edit because I want to stress that it was chosen from the "candidate" UNIQUE NOT NULL column sets to be "the" "primary" one, aka the PK.